# zsh compadd - how to specify argument's description?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

With `_arguments` I can do `_arguments {-h,--help}'[Show help]'`, but how to specify `'Show help'` message in `compadd` parameters? Cannot find that in [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Builtin-Commands)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old. I had this question recently and this is how I solved it.

```sh
function _foo {
  
  local -a _descriptions _values

  _descriptions=(
    'foo -- Description of foo'
    'bar -- Description of bar'
    'baz -- Description of baz'
  )

  _values=(
    'bar'
    'foo'
    'baz'
  )

  # Vertical window completion
  compadd -d _descriptions -a _values
  #$~ foo
  # bar -- Description of bar
  # baz -- Description of baz
  # foo -- Description of foo

  # Horizontal completion
  # compadd -d _descriptions -a _values
  #$~ foo
  # bar -- Description of bar  baz -- Description of baz  foo -- Description of foo
}

compdef _foo foo
```

Note: that this works only with arrays. If you have a string, you must convert it to an array

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do that with just `compadd`. That's why `_arguments` calls `_describe` under the hood. You might want to look into that function, if you want to customize things a bit more than `_arguments` allows.

However, if you really want to do it by making calls to `compadd`: What `_describe` does is add empty (that is, unselectable) completions with the `-E` option to `compadd` and then sets descriptions for them with the `-d`. Laying them out correctly, though, is a major PITA. That's why `_describe` uses a builtin function `compdescribe` for this—which is unfortunately poorly documented.

You're probably better off just sticking to `_arguments` and/or `_describe`.